# Extract text from JSON via PHP Script, where JSON input is not known

Tags: php, json

Below is the JSON that user is going to input, Please note user can input any JSON format, I am just giving an example.

I need to know how to extract only Text from JSON via PHP script.
Please note JSON can be any form or type may not be necessary like below :

```
{
    "title": "rahul",
    "date": [
        {
            "day": 25,
            "month": "May",
            "year": 2020        }
    ],
    "room": {
        "class": "super",
        "number": 666
    }
}
```

I need output as below :

```
title rahul
date
day 25
month May
year 2020
room
class super
number 666
```

I used `json_decode` but it is not properly giving me above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode()` would be the best answer for this, it'll parse any valid JSON string, and return either an Object or an Array.

Given you've said that you could have any JSON structure, I've created a recursive solution that'll give you the output you're after:

```php
<?php

$inputJson = <<<JSON
{ "title": "rahul", "date": [ { "day": 25, "month": "May", "year": 2020 } ], "room": { "class": "super", "number": 666 } }
JSON;

if ($decoded = json_decode($inputJson, true)) {
    outputRecursive($decoded);
}

function outputRecursive($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (!is_int($key)) {
                echo $key . PHP_EOL;
            }

            outputRecursive($value);
        } else {
            if (is_int($key)) {
                echo $value . PHP_EOL;

                continue;
            }
            echo $key . ' ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
title rahul
date
day 25
month May
year 2020
room
class super
number 666
```

Comment: Sorry, I just checked other based on your login, it is not giving correct answer :   {"DATA":{"KEY":"VALUE"},"SOME_OTHER_DATA":["value1","value2"]}      --->   Wrong decode : DATA KEY VALUE SOME_OTHER_DATA 0 value1 1 value2

Comment: @techexpert, that's not a valid JSON string there, also you've not explained what you're expecting the output to be. I've corrected the JSON to `{"KEY":"VALUE","SOME_OTHER_DATA":["value1","value2"]}` - hopefully that's what you were after? If it was the numeric keys you were trying to avoid from showing, I've excluded these now in the updated example above.